# "Operating system wasn't found ,try disconnecting drives and press cltr+alt+del to restart "

Tags: 12.10

I have downloaded the ubuntu 12.10 32 bit iso and extrated the files to usb bootable drive and i want to install it along with windows 8 on my laptop. When i insert usb bootable disk and tried to restart the lappy on start up it is saying

"Operating system wasn't found ,try disconnecting drives and press cltr+alt+del to restart " error on black screen while installing 12.10 on windows 8 through bootable usb drive

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks,
Gopichand

Answer (score 1):

You need to burn a disk containing Ubuntu.
go out to the drug store and buy a pack of five blank DVDR disks.
on your computer : 
download the latest version of Ubuntu : 
from here : http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current
windows : 
go to http://imgburn.com and download the program
insert one of the blank DVDs from the pack you bought at the drug store.
find your Ubuntu ISO, right click on it, and select "burn using img burn".
uncheck the "verify" box
change "aws" to "2x"
click write
wait for the disk to finish burning
boot from it
mac : go to utilities > disk utility
insert one of your blank disks
click the "burn" button
find your iso
click burn
wait for burn to complete
boot from your disk
linux : 
open a terminal
insert one of your blank disks
in the terminal,
enter
sudo wodim /path/to/your/ubuntu.iso
and enter your password when prompted.
When your prompt returns, boot from your disk.
When you hear the drum sound, click your language, and then click the "install ubuntu" button.
click through the prompts, until at the "this computer currently contains ***_*__**" where **__*_*** is your current operating system. Click the "erase ***_*___** and install Ubuntu" option, and then click continue. Keep on following prompts until your install completes, then remove the disk and click reboot.

Comment: Hi i did as suggested... when i clicked continue by selecting option install ubuntu inside windows .. a screen came saying that please remove installation media and close the tr(if any) and hit enter.. i removed dvd and pressed enter it restarted into windows 8 only .. i didn't find any option for dual boot it directly loads windows 8... Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a bootable USB Drive when you copy the Data from the Disk. This won't make the USB Drive bootable.

You have several possibilities:

- Create a USB Drive with the Ubuntu-Tool while running a Live-Disk
- Use unetbootin: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Or just burn the ISO on a CD an install from it.

Comment: Thanks for responding...I have created bootable usb drive using commands in cmd prompt and then copied the extracted files. first i tried unetbooting also but didn't work.. Could you please tell me what is meaning of live-disk?

Comment: You can boot and run Ubuntu from a CD, without installing it. This is a Live-Disk. If you have downloaded Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Website, you have a Live Disk. Try to burn it and boot you PC from the CD.

Comment: Dude i'm confused can you please give me simple steps... i downloaded ISO from ubuntu site next what to do?...and also what Live-Disk does mean?

Comment: @Gopichand, What commands did you use to create the bootable USB drive?

Comment: @saji89 : http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-USB-Bootable check dis link i have followed 1to7 steps...

Comment: @prophecy201 : Any suggestions please?